# All documents are getting stored in one shard in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a 4 shard mongo cluster and all documents that I store are going into one shard. I am using the primary key from my RDBMS table (which is a sequence number) as the shard key. I am a beginner and wondering if this has got to do with any configuration and where to look?

```
Shard rs1 at rs1/10.158.66.183:27020,10.158.66.184:27020
 data : 148.57Gb docs : 39100284 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 148.57Gb
 estimated docs per chunk : 39100284

Totals
 data : 148.57Gb docs : 39100284 chunks : 1
 Shard rs1 contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3kb
```

sh.status()

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("537c935b2158e8ca4fea274a")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/HOST1:27020,HOST2:27020" }
    {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/HOST3:27020,HOST4:27020" }
    {  "_id" : "rs2",  "host" : "rs2/HOST5:27020,HOST6:27020" }
    {  "_id" : "rs3",  "host" : "rs3/HOST7:27020,HOST7:27020" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }
        test.students
            shard key: { "grades" : 1 }
            chunks:
                rs0 1
            { "grades" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "grades" : { $maxKey : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1000, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "foo",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs1" }
    {  "_id" : "db1",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs1" }
        db1.collection1
            shard key: { "_id" : 1, "name" : 1 }
            chunks:
                rs1 1
            { "_id" : { $minKey : 1 }, "name" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { $maxKey : 1 }, "name" : { $maxKey : 1 } } on : rs1 Timestamp(1000, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "db",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "rs0" }
    {  "_id" : "collection1",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rs0" }
```

Comment: Can you show us a sh.status? According to that you only have one shard

Comment: added sh.status(). I modified the shard key a little bit since original post as I trying to debug this problem. My collection is db1.collection1. Thanks.

Comment: Did you set this up? It is interesting that collection starts on anything but the master shard, there is a way to do this but it is not standard to mongodb

Comment: Also according to that your index has all the same values, both min and max key are 1, what are the values in these fields? I can think it is possible that you have a chunk too large to split and the balancer has not runon it since

Comment: I set this up by following the documentation on mongodb.org

Comment: in general if we have 4 replica sets configured in our cluster, when we index data, it should get distributed to all 4 sets right?

Comment: In this case yes, you have enough documents and your chunhk size is, well, too large. The only thing I can think of is maybe the chunks didn't split correctly or the index wasn't built correctly by mongod

Comment: I didn't create any indexes on the collection. Do I need to? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently not: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key-indexes/ it says it will automatically create an index for you now, hmm I may need to test if and when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the cluster configuration (for config servers, replica sets) and restarted. After that Sharding worked for my collections.